# using CASE and WHERE statement and counter SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to do query. I use Microsoft SQL.

- If product is equal to FAST...

  - and tree_level is equal 0,1,2,3,4,5, then count the number of 0,1,2,3,4,5.  For example if there is number of 30 item which contain "0,1,2,3,4,5".  Then multiply 30*2.
  - and tree_level equal -1, then count number of -1 and multiply by 2
- If product is equal to MOBIL and tree_level is equal 0,1,2,3,4,5 count the number and multiply by 3
- If product is equal to FACE...

  - and tree_level is equal to 0,1,2,3,4,5, then count the number of 0,1,2,3,4,5 and multiply by 3
  - and tree_level equal -1, then count number of -1 and multiply by 2

How can ı use where, case and counter statements together?  I can not do that.

```
select
    DS.PersTel ,
    DW.AD ,
    DW.SOYAD ,
    DS.RefPhoner   ,
    DS.Product ,
    DS.Tree_level 

WHERE DS.Product like '%FACE%' (
CASE  
WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (0,1,2,3,4,5) THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 3 
WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (-1) THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 2
END  

WHERE DS.Product like '%MOBIL%'  (
CASE DS.Tree_level
WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (0,1,2,3,4,5) THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 3 
END  )

WHERE DS.Product like '%FAST%' (
CASE  DS.Tree_level
WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (0,1,2,3,4,5) THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 2 
WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (-1) THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 2
END  )


    from dw_prod.FRTN.DIG_SEFER  AS DS 
    inner join dw_prod.dbo.DW_MUST AS DW 
    ON DW.CEP_TEL = DS.PersTel
```

**updated case part**

```
       select
        DS.PersTel ,
            DW.AD ,
            DW.SOYAD ,
            DS.RefPhoner   ,
            DS.Product ,
            DS.Tree_level 
    CASE  
    WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (0,1,2,3,4,5)AND DS.Product LIKE '%FACE%' THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 3 
    WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (-1) THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 2
    END AS Answer1 

    CASE DS.Tree_level
    WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (0,1,2,3,4,5) AND DS.Product LIKE '%MOBIL%' THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 3 
    END AS Answer2 

    CASE  DS.Tree_level
    WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (0,1,2,3,4,5) AND DS.Product LIKE '%FAST%' THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 2 
    WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (-1) THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 2
    END AS Answer3

  from d.FR  AS Ds 
            inner join d.dbo.DW AS Dw 
            ON DW.CEP_TEL = DS.PersTel
```

Comment: Please provide sample output for what you want to achieve.

Comment: What's the actual problem?

Comment: I CAN not use with counter , where , case algorthm together

Comment: You can't use "count" in "where", use it on "having"

Comment: ı delete where statement but still counter not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
select
    product,
    tree_level,
    count(1) over (partition by product,tree_level_category) 
        * case when product like '%FACE%'
               then case tree_level_category
                        when '0-5' then 3
                        when '-1' then 2
                    end
               when product like '%MOBIL%'
               then case tree_level_category
                        when '0-5' then 3
                    end
               when product like '%FAST%'
               then case tree_level_category
                   when '0-5' then 2
                   when '-1' then 2
              end
        end 
from (
    select
        product,
        tree_level,
        case when tree_level in (0,1,2,3,4,5)
             then '0-5'
             when tree_level = '-1'
             then '-1'
             else null 
        end tree_level_category
    from
       product
) as t
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f4f4f/4)

Comment: how can ı use it with join

Comment: Just add it in in the lower query.